# Chinese character which is from HTTP was broken in iphone development

Tags: iphone, xml, http, character-encoding

I have problem with iphone development.

I have to receive the xml data from HTTP. The data contain Chinese character as follows:

> < CityNameChn >澳门 - MFM< /CityNameChn >

When I receive the xml data, Some Chinese character was broken as follow :

> < CityNameChn >澳 &#x95e8 ; - MFM< /CityNameChn >

"门" has been changed an "&#x95e8 ;"

Relevant code is as follow :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
       [self.tempResponseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection
{
        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tempResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@" response : %@" , responseData);
}
```

The log result is as follow :

> response : CityNameChn >澳 &#x95e8 ; - MFM< /CityNameChn >

Why is character  broken? is this encoding problem? but, Server send me the data by UTF - 8

what is the solution to  this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me a lot with the "&" sign.  It is probably due to the fact that in the XML code on the server, &#x95e8 ; represents that Chinese character.  If you wanted to fix this problem, I would perform find and replace methods on the string (it needs to be an NSMutableString) and replace all instances of "&#x95e8 ;" with "门".  Hopefully this is the only Chinese character where this is a problem.

Also, if you do not format the string as UTF8, does this change anything?  You did say that the XML response it in UTF-8, so probably not.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell why one of the Chinese characters gets encoded as a character reference and the other is passed as is, but in general, when processing XML data, you should be prepaped to dealing with character references: `&#xnnnn;` (with hexadecimal number nnnn) and `&#nnnn;` (with decimal number nnnn). They are valid in XML data even in situations where they are not needed, i.e. the characters could be entered as such in the encoding in use.